# Why Ember don't renders the child resource?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

This simple Ember application should list posts. But Ember doesn't renders the post template.

**JS:**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts', function(){
    this.resource('post', { path: '/:post_id'});
  });
});

App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string')
});
App.Post.FIXTURES = [
  { id: 1, title: "First post" },
  { id: 2, title: "Second post" },
  { id: 3, title: "Last post" },
];

App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('post');
  }
});
```

**HTML body tag:**

```
<body>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  {{#link-to 'posts'}}
  posts
  {{/link-to}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts">
    <h3>Posts list</h3>
    <ul>
      {{#each post in model}}
        <li>
           {{#link-to 'post' post}}
              {{post.title}}
           {{/link-to}}
        </li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="post">
    Post #{{id}}: {{title}}
  </script>
</body>
```

[JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qeviqe/4/) of this example.

**Note:** If I remove the `posts` template and access `/#/posts/1` URL, Ember renders the `post` template.

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25817621/emberjs-complex-routing/25823132#25823132, it might be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an `{{outlet}}` is added to posts template then the post template will be rendered.

example 1

http://jsbin.com/yepica/1

However if you do not want the template to be nested then rename `posts` to `posts/index`.

example 2

http://jsbin.com/wedufo/1

---

*from documentation*

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_resources

*helpful article*

http://ugisozols.com/blog/2013/11/05/understanding-nesting-in-emberjs/

---

example 1
**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  {{#link-to 'posts'}}
  posts
  {{/link-to}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts">
    <h3>Posts list</h3>
    <ul>
      {{#each post in model}}
        <li>
           {{#link-to 'post' post}}
              {{post.title}}
           {{/link-to}}
        </li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
{{outlet}}

  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="post">
    Post #{{id}}: {{title}}
  </script>
```

example 2
**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  {{#link-to 'posts'}}
  posts
  {{/link-to}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts/index">
    <h3>Posts list</h3>
    <ul>
      {{#each post in model}}
        <li>
           {{#link-to 'post' post}}
              {{post.title}}
           {{/link-to}}
        </li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>


  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="post">
    Post #{{id}}: {{title}}
  </script>
```